# ViewModelProviders is deprecated in 1.1.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

Looking at the [Google docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) for `ViewModel`, they show the below sample code on how to get a `ViewModel`:

```
val model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

When using the latest dependency `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1` there is no such class `ViewModelProviders`.

Going to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders) for `ViewModelProviders`, I saw a comment saying:

> This class was deprecated in API level 1.1.0. Use ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory

The problem is, when trying to use `ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory`, cannot find an equivalent `of` method to get the instance of the `ViewModel`.

What i tried doing:

```
ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application).create(PlayerViewHolder::class.java)
```

Hence the name of the method `create`, I get a new instance of the ViewModel every-time I call it, which is not what I am after.

Any ideas what is the replacement of deprecated code above?

Comment: use singleton pattern or change to AndroidX

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**UPDATE 2020-06-16**: *Presently* `ViewModelProviders` is deprecated and should no longer be used. This question and answer were from late 2018, when that was not the case. This question and answer are also for the older Architecture Components edition of `ViewModelProviders`, not the AndroidX edition.

---

> When using the latest dependency `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1` there is no such class `ViewModelProviders`.

Yes, there is. To demonstrate this:

- Create a new project in Android Studio 3.2.1 (with Kotlin, `minSdkVersion` 21, "empty activity" template)
- Add `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1` to the dependencies of the `app` module

This will give you an `app/build.gradle` like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.commonsware.myandroidarch"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

You will then see that library show up in "External Libraries" with that class:

[image: External Libraries]

And you will be able to reference that class:

```
package com.commonsware.myandroidarch

import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val provider = ViewModelProviders.of(this)
  }
}
```

> Going to the documentation for ViewModelProviders, I saw a comment saying: This class was deprecated in API level 1.1.0. Use ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory

That comment is underneath the `ViewModelProviders.DefaultFactory` class entry and refers to that class, not `ViewModelProviders`:

[image: Documentation Screenshot]

> Any ideas what is the replacement of deprecated code above?

Use `ViewModelProviders`.

Comment: @TareKKhoury: That would explain it! Keeping track of which modules need which dependencies definitely can be a challenge. I'm glad to hear that you got it working!

Comment: This is not true anymore, `ViewModelProviders.of()` no longer exists.

Answer (score 477):

I use lifecycle-extensions `2.2.0` version:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
```

It should work, using `ViewModelProvider` constructor.

```
// With ViewModelFactory   
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, YourViewModelFactory).get(YourViewModel::class.java)


//Without ViewModelFactory
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(YourViewModel::class.java)
```

2020/5/15 Update

I found another elegant way to achieve this, Android KTX can help

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.4"
val viewmodel: MYViewModel by viewModels()
val viewmodel: MYViewModel by viewModels { myFactory } //With factory
```

Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary#viewmodels

2020/06/25: corrected the case of the delegate

Comment: I am kind of sick of the constant "depreciation" cycle by Google.

Comment: ViewModelProviders.of() has been deprecated. You can pass a Fragment or FragmentActivity to the new ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner) constructor to achieve the same functionality. (aosp/1009889)

Comment: Java equivalent: `YourViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(YourViewModel.class);`

Comment: I worry if some day Google will deprecate the `TextView` or `EditText` and introduce a new Component.

Comment: androidx lifecycle-viewmodel 2.1.0 does not have a constructor without a factory. using simply (this) does not work.
ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner, Factory) and ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStore, Factory) are the only constructors

Comment: Any reason for the change?

Comment: When software evolves, old implementations get deprecated. This is natural, there is no use in fighting that.

Comment: @AFD true. Some of google's libraries change API every month, like WebRTC android. Very frustrating when trying to learn the framework from tutorials

Comment: So we hae to create new objects each time?

Comment: The code `val viewmodel: MYViewModel by viewModels { myFactory }` and `myFactory` only worked when used as properties, for me. When I tried to assign them both as local variables in a function, this didn't work. Why is that?

Comment: I've been programming in Android for years and it's the most depressing thing ever.

Comment: Note: as per the Lifecycle 2.2.0 release notes, the lifecycle-extensions artifact is no longer published. The APIs in lifecycle-extensions have been deprecated. Instead, add dependencies for the specific Lifecycle artifacts you need.

Answer (score 104):

As @FantasyFang mentioned in his answer, use the lastest version for the `lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions` which in this moment is `2.2.0-alpha03`. So you should add in your build.gradle file the following line:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-alpha03'
```

For those who are using Java, to solve this, pass those arguments directly to ViewModelProvider's [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.html#ViewModelProvider(android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner,%20android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory)):

```
MyViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, myViewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

Or if you don't use a factory, simply use:

```
MyViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

Without passing your the factory object.

Comment: You should be using the following in build.gradle:

implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"

As noted in https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle

The APIs in lifecycle-extensions have been deprecated. Instead, add dependencies for the specific Lifecycle artifacts you need.

Answer (score 78):

### Import

Deprecated From:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
```

To:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
```

---

### Using

Deprecated From:

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this, provider).get(VM::class.java)
```

To:

```
ViewModelProvider(this, provider).get(VM::class.java)
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Perfect. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 61):

As of 2.2.0. the lifecycle-extensions has been deprecated. Refer to [Google Documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#kotlin).

This is the cut from the page:

> The APIs in lifecycle-extensions have been deprecated. Instead, add
>   dependencies for the specific Lifecycle artifacts you need.

The new libraries are:

```
// ViewModel and lifecycle support for java
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:${versions.lifecycle}"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:${versions.lifecycle}"

// ViewModel and lifecycle support for kotlin
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:${versions.lifecycle}"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:${versions.lifecycle}"
```

The new code for JAVA:

```
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

Or for Kotlin:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: Do we keep the ViewModelProvider isntsance or have to recreate it again, in which case, all underlying instances will also be destroyed. I don't the reason of re-creating it if the idea is to watch the lifecycle of the fragment/activity

Comment: Thanks for including Java - some of us still have to maintain legacy code.

Answer (score 37):

Early in 2020, **Google have deprecated the ViewModelProviders class**, in version 2.2.0 of the androidx lifecycle library.

It's no longer necessary to use ViewModelProviders to create an instance of a ViewModel, you can pass your Fragment or Activity instance to the ViewModelProvider constructor instead.

If you use the code like:

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CalculatorViewModel::class.java)
```

you'll get a warning that **ViewModelProviders has been deprecated.**

To avoid using deprecated libraries, make the following changes:

1. In the build.gradle (Module: app) file, use version 2.2.0 of the lifecycle 
    components:

   ```
   implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
   implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0"
   ```

   If you want to use the ViewModel from a Fragment instead, use

   ```
   implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.2"
   ```

   fragment-ktx automatically includes activity-ktx, **so you don't need to 
     specify both in the dependencies.**
2. You need to specify Java 8 in the android section :

   ```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 28
       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "com.kgandroid.calculator"
           minSdkVersion 17
           targetSdkVersion 28
           versionCode 1
           versionName "1.0"
           testInstrumentationRunner 
       "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
              'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }

       kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "1.8" }
   }
   ```
3. In your Fragment or Activity, change the import to:

   **import androidx.activity.viewModels**
4. The code to create a ViewModel then becomes:

   ```
   val viewModel: CalculatorViewModel by viewModels()
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CalculatorViewModel::class.java)
   ```

   **Use the viewModel object as :**

   ```
   val viewModel: CalculatorViewModel by viewModels()

   viewModel.newNumber.observe(this, Observer<String> { 
       stringResult -> newNumber.setText(stringResult) 
   })
   ```

   where **newNumer is a LiveData object**

   In a Fragment that you want to share the Activity's ViewModel, you'd use

   ```
   val viewModel: CalculatorViewModel by activityViewModels()
   ```

That's the equivalent of passing the Activity instance in the (deprecated) `ViewModelProviders.of()` function.

Answer (score 26):

ViewModelProviders.of() has been deprecated.
[image]

Use ViewModelProvider constructors directly as they now handle the default ViewModelProvider.Factory role.

```
 mainActivityViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score 20):

Probably you can just use:

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory()).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

without needing to add `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1` as the dependency.

Answer (score 15):

Actually, what does the `ViewModelProviders.of()` method do under the hood?

```
@Deprecated
@NonNull
@MainThread
public static ViewModelProvider of(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
    return new ViewModelProvider(fragment);
}
```

It takes `Fragment` as an argument, creates `ViewModelProvider` object and passes the fragment directly to `ViewModelProvider` constructor.

We can use the same way too.

E.g. Before:

```
OurViewModel mOurViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(OurViewModel.class);
```

After:

```
OurViewModel mOurViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(OurViewModel.class);
```

Comment: If you implement a Factory, you have another way: `ViewModelProvider` has a constructor which expects both a `ViewModelStoreOwner` and a `Factory`.

Answer (score 14):

In case you watch a video from `Udacity` where you create a `GameViewModel` and you do not want to write deprecated code just replace:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GameViewModel::class.java)
```

with the following code:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(GameViewModel::class.java)
```

and return back to reading ASAP!!

Answer (score 13):

Yes @Tarek, it is deprecated. Use now with AndroidX:

```
val yourViewModel = ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory().create(YourVideoModel::class.java)
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. You should be using a `ViewModelProvider(viewModelStoreOwner, factory).get(YourVideoModel::class.java)` otherwise your `onCleared()` won't work correctly, and ViewModel won't be kept across config change. **Do not use this answer.**

Answer (score 12):

Use ViewModelProvider directly instead of user ViewModelProviders.of() as mentioned in the docs.

```
ViewModelProvider(this).get(XViewModel::class.java)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders

Answer (score 9):

I'm using `android X` and also had this issue.

**First of all**, you should add these dependencies to your `Gradle`:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
```

***In my case, the $lifecycle_version was `2.2.0-rc02`***

**Second:**
The import for the `ViewModelProvider` should be:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
```

Than you can initial your vIewModel like the examples below:

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, YourFactoryInstace).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , but when i use it then viewmodel observe and fields databinding is no longer work

Comment: I believe `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler` is obsoleted by `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8`.

Answer (score 7):

If you use Kotlin, you can use the property delegate `viewModels()` like this:

```
val viewModel: YourViewModel by viewModels()
```

Source: https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/solution-to-deprecated-method-viewmodelproviders-of/16833

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
YourViewModel yourViewModel = new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication()).create(YourViewModel.class);
```

Comment: will this not create new instance every time when on create called? suppose lifcyle like this, stop , onCreate ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this instead:

```
viewModel= ViewModelProvider(this).get(YourViewModel::class.java)
```

"this" in the parentheses is the owner of YourViewModel instance.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert but i have a line of code that solved my problem in Java. Hope this helps someone.

```
viewModel = 
new ViewModelProvider
.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication())
.create(ViewModel.class);
```

As i said i would love to provide more details, but this fixed this problem for me.

Comment: This code is wrong, `onCleared()` won't be called this way and your ViewModel will be recreated each time (not kept for config changes).

Comment: Can you explain a bit more with a certain example, what would fix my mistake? Please, paste a reference to the explanation or anything that would make things clearer

Comment: `viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class)`. If your `AndroidViewModel` doesn't get the `Application`, then you have a version mismatch between Lifecycle and Activity/Fragment.

Comment: Ok, so calling getApplicationContext is wrong? Should it just be getContext?

Comment: The issue is creating a `new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(` instead of a `new ViewModelProvider(`.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is for Java but you can understand main point. Solution is that you need use **ViewModelProvider** because [ViewModelProviders deprecated:](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders)

```
//Do not forget import it.
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;

ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication()).create(YourViewModel.class);
```

Example usage is:

```
YourViewModel yourViewModel = new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication()).create(YourViewModel.class);
```

Also, do not forget update ***Gradle Dependencies***: [Check here for last versions of them](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle)

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0'
```

*!!! However, be careful because some answers recommend this solution but it did not work for me:*

```
yourViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(YourViewModel.class);
```

Because when I used this way, I got below Error Message:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.canerkaseler.mvvmexample.ViewModel

Comment: This answer is wrong. You need to pass the factory to a ViewModelProvider. If you directly invoke `create`, then `onCleared()` won't work correct.

Comment: In fact, you literally just said not to use the correct answer. Sounds like you had a mismatch between your `androidx.core` and your `androidx.lifecycle` dependencies.

Comment: Normally I wrote the factory to ViewModelProvider. However, you deleted it. 

ContactViewModel contactViewModel = new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication()).create(ContactViewModel.class);

Why did you delete it on my answer? You passed wrong codes.

Answer (score 3):

Update: July 20 2022

```
private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding
    private lateinit var homeMvvM : HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        homeMvvM = ViewModelProvider(this)[HomeViewModel::class.java]
```

this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

When you use dagger then u'll pass factory in constructor

```
  MobileViewModel mobileViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,providerFactory).get(MobileViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

I kept trying and ended up with this solution in Kotlin, you should be able to try it in java too.

MainActivity.kt

```
 val provider : ViewModelProvider = ViewModelProvider(this)
 val VM = provider.get(ViewModelClass::class.java)
```

build.gradle

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0"
```

Current version of the lifecycle libraries is 2.3.0 as of 2/2/2021, Refer to https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle to check for current version.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using factory.

```
ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory
            .getInstance(getApplication())
            .create(DashboardViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply update from

> ViewModelProviders.of(this,
> provider).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)

to

> ViewModelProvider(this,
> provider).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Activity ktx
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.5.1'

//Fragment ktx
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.1'
```

Simplest way of creating view models:

```
class MyViewModel() : ViewModel() {

}

class SomeActivity:AppCompatActivity(){
  private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_some)
}
}
```

View Model With Constructor Arguments:

```
class MyViewModel(list:List<String>) : ViewModel() {


 class Factory(list:List<String>) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        @Suppress("unchecked_cast")
        override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            return MyViewModel(list) as T
        }
    }
}
class SomeActivity:AppCompatActivity(){

  private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels(){
MyViewModel.Factory(listOf<String>("a"))}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. if anything doesn't work try this piece of code into your oncreate and edit it according to your file and boom you are gtg

```
val model = ViewModelProvider(viewModelStore,ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application)).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
```

// you just need to change the model class

Comment: Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
private  val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by viewModels(ownerProducer = { requireActivity() })


ownerProducer = { requireActivity() } // This is only required if you want to share same view model among different fragments.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Library of Lifecycle 2.3.1 and add below dependency in **build.gradle** (Module-level)

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions-ktx:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.6'
```

Declare ***viewModels()*** in your **Kotlin** code as per below:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels

private val cartViewModel: CartViewModel by viewModels()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code in your build.gradle module level

```
 android {
 kotlinOptions {
    freeCompilerArgs += [
        '-Xjvm-default=enable'
    ]
  }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
 LocationViewModel locationViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(LocationViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score -7):

it should work this way

```
 viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this@MainActivity).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: While your code would instance the class is will not create the connection to the view state required to have the View Model class to correctly respond to life cycle events.

You need to instance View Models in the correct manner so they respond and honor life cycles of their parents else they be recreated fresh and blank each time.

Comment: As noted above by the OP and others; the ViewModelProviders class has been deprecated.  See: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders.html