# ViewModelProviders.of(this).get not working How I resolve that?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mvvm, android-mvvm

[image]

I use That Library `implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'`
When I Create The Project it is Working perfectly but I need to update my app. it is not working

Comment: Check similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53903762/viewmodelproviders-is-deprecated-in-1-1-0

Comment: It should be new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);