# How can i implement shared viewmodel across fragments in java?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

I am new to android and working on an application where i have use shared ViewModel across fragments there are a lot of help for kotlin but for java there is nothing. Please guide me if possible.?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) and its Java example?

Comment: Also [fragment documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate).

Comment: @CommonsWare yes i have read them but did not get it properly..

Comment: ViewModelProviders has been deprecated - see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53903762/viewmodelproviders-is-deprecated-in-1-1-0)

Answer (score 0):

Follow [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing), and remember to use the same `ViewModelStoreOwner`, like this:

```html
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {

}

public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    private SharedViewModel model;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //pass the host Activity
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
    }
}

public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         //pass the host Activity
        SharedViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
    }
}
```