# CreationExtras must have a value by `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY`

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm trying to implement navigation in my app which is built with Jetpack Compose, but when I try to navigate from a screen to another I get:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY`

I'm using:

```
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0"
```

And here is the code:

```
if(viewModel.isAuthenticated) {
    navController.navigate(Screen.Profile.route)
}
```

Comment: For me this issue is resolved by updating to version `1.1.0-alpha01` of the hilt navigation compose library

Comment: @MEX It also works that way, I tested it. If you want, you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Hilt release notes for 2.43](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases) flags a dependency incompatibility:

> As part ViewModel bug fixes, dependencies were updated as below. androidx.navigation users will need to update to 2.5.0 to interoperate. These libraries require building with SDK 31. To build with SDK 31, AGP users will need to use AGP 7.0+. This will also require using JDK11.
>
> - androidx.activity and androidx.fragment to 1.5.0
> - androidx.lifecycle to 2.5.0
> - androidx.savedstate to 1.2.0

Comment: Finally they solved the problem. Thank you for answering this question.

Comment: I missed "androidx.fragment" implementation. After adding fragment dependency its work for me.

Answer (score 57):

@Dragan.T 's answer is correct.

Adding

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3
```

Solved my problem. As for why we need to add, I am not so sure.

Edit: Be sure to replace 2.5.3 with latest version.

Comment: I cannot see any reason why we need another dependency as long as we are using one that provides everything that is necessary.

Comment: You are using hilt navigation not compose navigation so maybe hilt navigation provides stuff only related to hilt injection not for compose viewmodel creation. I am also not sure about this but the solution did work

Comment: It already provides stuff for navigation, so it's not about that.

Comment: It worked for me too, 2.4.2 had problem but it was removed after I changed to 2.5.1.

Answer (score 25):

If you use Compose with Fragments, then you may not have the Fragments dependency where `viewModels()` is defined.

Adding:

`implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.2"`

to my build.grade script fixed it for me (previously this was a transitive dependency).

Comment: Agree, my project was using pure Hilt+Fragments+viewModels() (No navigation components yet) and I have got a runtime error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY" in the line where Hilt was injecting the viewModel by viewModels()/ Simply updating the androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx library from 1.4.1 to 1.5.2 fixed the error.

Comment: This worked for me. I'm not using Jetpack Compose, but I am using `Hilt+Fragments+viewModels()` like the above person. I needed this. Wish Hilt document mentioned this. Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

Insert  `implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.1"` into your gradle file. If you already have it, be sure it's updated with the   latest (2.5.1) version.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question. But why would I add another dependency since I already have one? Hilt already provides all the necessary methods for navigation, right?

Comment: Hilt-navigation-compose library just provide methods and annotations for creating necessary scopes and init navigation graph with dependency injection, but you should  add "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.1" for working with compose nav.

Comment: `androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0` already contains a navigate method, I have no error in code. It just simply complains when I need to navigate from one screen to another.

Answer (score 9):

Just adding this to your `app/build.gradle` fixed this issue:

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.6.0'
```

##### Example:

```
dependencies {

    // ...
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.6.0'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This issue is resolved by updating to version `1.1.0-alpha01` of the hilt navigation compose library.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had to update the

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.2'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to upgrade two dependencies: Hilt and androidx.navigation. The curious issue is that after upgrading it, the error is gone, but if I downgrade again to previous versions, the error doesn't appear again. These are the dependencies I changed:

```
    navigation_version = "2.5.3" // was 2.5.1
    dagger_hilt_version = "2.44.2" // was 2.43.2

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$navigation_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$navigation_version"

    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$dagger_hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$dagger_hilt_version"
    testImplementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:$dagger_hilt_version"
    kaptTest "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$dagger_hilt_version"
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:$dagger_hilt_version"
    kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$dagger_hilt_version"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that updating the versions of the following AndroidX libraries might resolve the issue:

- androidx.activity
- androidx.fragment
- androidx.lifecycle
- androidx.savedstate

Alternatively, you could use the following versions:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.6'
}
```

These versions have been tested and found to work well together for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can to continue use this library:

```
androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0
```

Only you are sure that **ViewModel** is initialized in a Composable that is root in your activity.
For example:

```
    setContent {
        AndroidLearningTheme {
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
            ) {
                HeroesScreen()
            }
        }
    }
```

Your **Composable**

```
@Composable
fun HeroesScreen(
    viewModel: HeroesViewModel = hiltViewModel()
)
```

Comment: Oh, thank you Carlos for taking the time to answer this unsolved issue. I didn't try it yet. So, let's it works, how about the other composables?

Comment: I tried to create the ViewModel only inside the activity and pass them as parameter, but it doesn't work either. I get the same error :(

Comment: Sorry, don't worries, maybe I need more code for to replicate the error, can you share the repository project with error? @JoanP.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error due to `ViewModelProviders` and after spending a long time and changing to `ViewModelProvider` than it get fixed

[ViewModelProviders is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53903762/viewmodelproviders-is-deprecated-in-1-1-0)

Old:

```
ViewModelProviders.of(context, context.defaultViewModelProviderFactory)
    .get(XYZViewModel::class.java)
```

New one fixed:

```
ViewModelProvider(
    context,
    context.defaultViewModelProviderFactory
)[XYZViewModel::class.java]
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose` library to the current stable version `2.5.3` solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding `implementation("androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1")` fixed it.