# Jetpack Compose update to 1.2.0 leads to ClassCastException: ComposableLambdaImpl to Function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I updated a project from Jetpack compose 1.0.0 to 1.2.1. Therefore I increased the version to 1.2.1 for following dependencies:

```
    // ***** UI & Jetpack Compose *****
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:${SharedVersions.jetpackCompose}")
    // ViewBinding support to integrate xml views via AndroidView()
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-viewbinding:${SharedVersions.jetpackCompose}")
    // Tooling support (Previews, etc.)
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:${SharedVersions.jetpackCompose}")
    // Foundation (Border, Background, Box, Image, Scroll, shapes, animations, etc.)
    implementation("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:${SharedVersions.jetpackCompose}")
    // Material Design
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:${SharedVersions.jetpackCompose}")
    // Integration with observables
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:${SharedVersions.jetpackCompose}")
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:${SharedVersions.jetpackCompose}")
```

and set

```
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.3.2"
    }
```

Due to the dependencies/requirements of jetpack compose 1.2.1 I had to update following parts in my application to get it to compile:

```
compileSdk from 31 to 32
targetSdk from 31 to 32
gradle android plugin from 7.2.2 to 7.3.0
gradle 7.3.3 to 7.4.0
kotlin from 1.5.10 to 1.7.20
```

and minor code migrations to support update the new kotlin version.

After that the application compiles but it crashes on first start with:

```
ClassCastException: androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl cannot be cast to kotlin.jvm.functions.Function
```

The crash occurs when calling a function similiar to this:

```
fun <D> NavGraphBuilder.createAppNavGraphComposableDataAware(
    route: String,
    arguments: List<NamedNavArgument> = emptyList(),
    deepLinks: List<NavDeepLink> = emptyList(),
    content: @Composable (backStackEntry: NavBackStackEntry, data: D) -> Unit
) {
    addDestination(Destination(provider, content as as @Composable (NavBackStackEntry, Any?) -> Unit)
}
```

Any clues what changed inside the jetpack compose libs or compiler? Does anyone else has problems similiar to this when using Composable Lambdas?

Comment: Have you tried checking version compatibilities? https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

Comment: I checked, according to the docs it should be compatible, we use kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion 1.3.2 and Kotlin 1.7.20

Comment: I just tried updating my project with same compose/kotlin versions you have and it imploded, I got this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73302605/creationextras-must-have-a-value-by-saved-state-registry-owner-key and led me to this github issue https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/3484, I keep getting a `navigation` thing exception and I was able to solve it by adding the latest `androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx` which is `2.5.2`, I'm not sure if this will solve yours though. Just try to have the latest `navigation-fragment-ktx` and have it included in your modules.

Comment: hey @Sven did you manage to solve it? I'm having the same issue :(

Comment: hi @DanPonce no, I only have a workaround to `gradlew clean` the project and recompile it. After the first recompile it works until the next update. Then I have to clean again.