# Why do I use pure components but still need fragment dependencies?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I have a problem when using compose, then i found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73675462/14887783)

> If you use Compose with Fragments, then you may not have the Fragments dependency where viewModels() is defined.
>
> Adding:
>
> implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.2"

use Compose with Fragments, but I use Pure Compose, Also had this problem.
What am I missing? Or is there some connection between fragment and compose?

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val userViewModel: UserViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            Content(userViewModel)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Content(userViewModel: UserViewModel) {

    val lazyArticleItem = userViewModel.list().collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    thread {
        repeat(200) {
            userViewModel.insert(User())
        }
    }

    LazyColumn(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)) {
        items(lazyArticleItem) { user ->
            Text("user ${user?.id}")
        }
    }

}
```

The above is my ui interface code, based on this, I don't think I'm using fragment.

I want to declare my logic. I use Pure Compose instead of Fragment, but actually want to run the code must depend on `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you are using

```
val userViewModel: UserViewModel by viewModels()
```

You can access a ViewModel from any composable by calling the [`viewModel()`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#viewmodel) function.
Use:

```
val userViewMode : UserViewModel = viewModel()
```

To use the `viewModel()` functions, add the `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:x.x.x`

Answer (score -1):

In programming, **"fragment"** and **"compose"** can refer to two related concepts:

Fragment: In UI design, a fragment is a portion of an activity's UI, which can be reused in multiple activities or combined to form a single activity. It provides a way to modularize the UI and make it more manageable.

Compose: Compose is a modern UI toolkit for Android app development introduced by Google, which allows developers to build and style UI elements using composable functions. It provides a way to create and reuse UI components that can be combined to form a complete app UI.

Both concepts are aimed at making UI design and development more modular, reusable and maintainable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In my opinion, what you say is indeed different between them, but in fact Compose also needs fragment dependencies `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.2`