# As ViewModelProviders.of() is deprecated, how should I create object of ViewModel in the Activity?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, android-livedata, viewmodelproviders

```
error: cannot find symbol
        MainActivityViewModel model = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
```

I tried different solutions available but no luck for me.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57427078/12153321

Comment: Adding the new keyword worked for me.

MainActivityViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view model using the `by ViewModels()` kotlin property delegate:

```
private val viewModel: YourCustomViewModel by viewModels()
```

or you can use `ViewModelProvider` to create ViewModels and retain them in a store of the given `ViewModelStoreOwner`.

Check the official documentation for best practices:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders#of(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider#ViewModelProvider(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner)